# What is a Good Automated Testing Platform for RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, continuous-integration

For testing purposes for Ruby/Rails I use RSpec and I have well over 1000 tests that are already written in my application. Once the app goes live I want to have the tests run once a day on the production server (since all the code is there) and see if anything fails. The test itself will be run against test data and now production data. This is an effort so that any new code that is added in the future will not cause anything to unknowingly break.

I have found a few solutions:

- Travis-CI (only open-source ... not suitable for closed-source projects)
- Jenkins-CI (not sure if it works with or well with Ruby/RSpec/Rails)
- Watir (not sure if Ruby/Rspec works with it, but the tool itself is written in Ruby).

Preferably something that checks the codebase daily and then emails me when something isn't working.

I also plan on integrating JavaScript testing with the a testing library of my choice (I just need the automation platform for testing it).

Can someone provide me some insight as to which tool to use? Or does anyone have any other tools to recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins-CI works great with rspec, and can run your jasmine javascript testing, and your cucumber javascript tests as well.

The only thing I'd recommend is not to test on your production server itself. When you push changes to your source-control repository, Jenkins will download the new code and run your tests there. When you're green (tests pass), push the code to production.